# Create Json list with objects with a string and bool value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to create a list that consists of x number of objects that contains a name and a bool value

I want to create and send the list using ajax when this happens

This is in my Init

```
$('.si-accordion').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings('.accordion_tab').toggleClass('IsExpanded');
            SendSIInstance();
        });
```

Here is the method it calls

```
function SendSIInstance() {
        $('.si-accordion').hasClass('IsExpanded')
        {
            var NameValue = $('.si-accordion').text();

            alert($('.si-accordion').text());
        }
    }
```

In my example I have 5 tabs (Which has the class si-accordion)

When I click them I toggle the class IsExpanded

I then want to create a list with objects like:

a String: text of si-accordion

A bool: if it has the class IsExpanded (if its there its true, else false)

The list with these 5 objects should then be send using AJAX so I can work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
function SendSIInstance() {
    var arrayToSend = [];
    $('.si-accordion').each(function() {

        var expanded = $(this).hasClass('IsExpanded');

        var text = $(this).text();
        var obj = {
            expanded: expanded,
            text: text
        };
        arrayToSend.push(obj);
    });

     //Send arrayToSend through ajax

$.ajax({
    url: "yoururls",
    data: arrayToSend,
    success: function() {
        // code to invoke after ajax call returns
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question, but try this...

```
var list = [$('.si-accordion').text(), $('.si-accordion').hasClass('IsExpanded') ...];    
var xmlRequest = $.ajax({
    url: "target.php",
    data: list,
    success: function() {
        // code to invoke after ajax call returns
    }
});
```